# best practice db tree sort

Tags: php, mysql

i have table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `tree` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `version` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sort` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rating` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `global_sort` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_22359CF6727ACA70` (`parent_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_22359CF6727ACA70` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `tree` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

in each level items can be sorted by: version, sort or rating.

I need to return all items in correct order.

as for now i use php recursion for each level & updating field global_sort concerning to level sorting.

any better ideas?

**EDIT1**

and as variant: if correct order must be only inside one level (no worries for global)?

**EDIT2**
i mean somshing like this
http://joxi.ru/WmYPUxjKTJAfVs5nCE4

when some items must be sorted by rating ask and some rating desc

Comment: You can sort using the order by "SELECT * FROM tree ORDER BY version, rating DESC"

Comment: & how this helps if in one item sorting rating desc and in othe rating asc?

Comment: "SELECT * FROM tree ORDER BY version ASC, rating DESC"